# How to get Mail files from Mountain Lion Time Machine backup in Mavericks?

Tags: mail.app, macos, time-machine, backup

I have upgraded my MBP to Mavericks and got the system to how I like etc. Tt has since backed up using Time Machine onto an external HD. Now it slipped my mind that I would like to have my e-mails on my new system from Mountain Lion.

I thought that a simple Enter Time Machine and then restoring the selected files that I need to make this happen would work, but upon entering time machine I cannot get into my ML backups on Mavericks.

Is there any way that I can get to my Mail files?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it after a long trawl through the internet. For any one else with a similar problem...

Thanks to this post by Alberto Ravasio [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19064774#19064774)

> Last but not least, navigate the TM disk within the Finder, (do not enter TM).
>   When you are on the date you are looking for, navigate the directory structure until you reach the Users folder.
>
> Open Terminal and type
>
> ```
> cd
> ```
>
> and a space, drag and drop your user name folder inside the Terminal window. That completes the cd command for you. Hit return.
>
> You are now into your user folder inside the TM disk. Type
>
> ```
> cd Library
> open .
> ```
>
> please note the dot after open. Last command opens a Finder window of the Library folder inside TM disk.
>
> Now you are ready to get what you need.

Comment: For a next Time: A Simpler way is to first export all the Mailboxes/Folders from within Mail with the Export Function before you Upgrade your System and after you can import them.